# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post_location' keeps referring me to far removed from __init__

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am try to get these fields from an post.html file I have with and post them back to a db, I have a login page and tried to mirror that the best I could but this one I cant seem to figure out.

```
                session["postdesc"] = ""

                flash("Required")

 

 

        else:

            pst = posts(postdesc, "")

            db.session.add(pst)

            db.session.commit()

            loc = posts(postlocation, "")

            db.session.add(loc)

            db.session.commit()

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post_location'
```

post_location I have above here

```
class posts(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id",db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post = db.Column(db.String(500))
    post_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    post_location = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self, post, post_date, post_location):
        self.post = post
        self.post_date = post_date
        self.post_location = post_location
```

Comment: Where are you confused?  Your profile for posts.`__init__` clearly lists three required arguments for every instantiation of a `posts` object.  In both uses, you give it only two, and apparently in the wrong order.  How did you expect this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your init function takes three parameters. You are only providing two. You can change

```
pst = posts(postdesc, "")
```

To

```
pst = posts(postdesc, "POST_DATA", "POST_LOCATION")
```

You would change POST_DATA and POST_LOCATION to what you desire. This will at least solve your current error.